# /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf の location の default_type について

Tags: nginx, letsencrypt

**下記修正で何か変化はあると考えられますか？**
・デフォルトの設定値はtext/plainと書いてあったので、その値を設定しても同じ結果になると思うのですが…

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf 
・修正前

```
server {
    //中略
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/acme-challenge;
    }
```

・修正後

```
server {
    //中略
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        default_type "text/plain";
        root /var/www/acme-challenge;
    }
```

---

**質問背景**
・上記修正を行ったら、下記エラーが表示されなくなったのですが、そんなはずはないと思い質問しました

> Invalid response from
>   https://hoge.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/xxxx

---

**環境**
・CentOS7
・Nginx